# WCF Rest uploading an image

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, streaming

I'm currently looking at the best way to upload an image to my existing WCF Json service, the service then saves the image to a folder on the server. Is it as simple as streaming the image? Or is there a different practice if you are using json?

Ultimately ill be sending an image from a mobile device to the service.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9451141/uploading-an-image-using-wcf-restful-service-full-working-example/34913111#34913111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a good code over this place.
Have a look. It should cater your need. The code has both client and server implementation

[MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Upload-files-using-a-REST-13f16af2/sourcecode?fileId=48404&pathId=787905472)

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajaxForm or ajaxSubmit from http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/
We used it to call an MVC action with our data, but had to use the iframe fallback option due to IE having issues with ajax and file inputs.

For a mobile site I would expect this to be useful. 
For a mobile app I would expect it to be more a case of streaming the image as you would any other type of file.